# Negative saturation using css

Tags: css, photoshop, hsl

I am cutting a Photoshop web layout. I have the following filter I would like to apply in css (I don't want to use an image in which the filter is already applied).

So I used these css properties to generate the following HSL (-64, -67, 0):

```
-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-64deg);
-webkit-filter: saturate(-67%);
```

But, there is a problem because if saturation is less than 0%, browser seems to clip it to 0%.

How can I do a negative saturation using css?

[image: filter]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid values are only from 0% to 100%

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#saturate()

The same is true for HSL in CSS

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#hsl-color

You just have to find out the scale PhotoShop uses and adjust accordingly. 
If you're using a preprocessor like SASS or LESS, you could do it there. 
So if PhotoShop goes from -100% to 100%, you could do `(100% + $val)/2`

(You could also use CSS [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), but this case is better for a preprocessor, or even manual calculation - just be sure to comment!)

Comment: Yes I already know. But is there a way/hack to do what I want?

Comment: You just have to find out the scale PhotoShop uses and adjust accordingly.  If you're using a preprocessor like SASS or LESS, you could do it there.

So if PhotoShop goes from -100% to 100%, you could do `(100% + $val)/2`

Comment: I think photoshop uses a linear scale between -100 and 100. It's easy enough to map it to the CSS scale (0-100%). Just add 100 and divide the result by two.

Comment: Can you copy paste your comment in your answer? I will upvote Thank you!